# Covering a cube with open balls centered at lattice points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm trying to prove that given $\epsilon >0$, the balls $B(\epsilon j;\epsilon)$ cover  a cube of the form $T = [-b,b]^n$, where $j=(j_1,...,j_n)$ ranges over all integral lattice points of $R^n$ which satisfy $\epsilon|j_i| \le 2b$, $1 \le i \le n$.

Let $x \in T, x=(x_1,...,x_n)$. Then it is enough to show that $x_i \in [-b,b]$ belongs to one of the open intervals belonging to the balls. This is the part I'm having trouble. How can I show that some interval $(\epsilon j_i-\epsilon, \epsilon j_i+\epsilon)$ contains $x_i$? Proving this has been troubling me for days any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, this is not true in high dimensions. As an example, take $n=5$, $T=[-1,1]^5$ and  $\epsilon =1$. The balls of radius $1$ centered at integer lattice points do not cover the point $(\frac12,\frac12,\frac12,\frac12,\frac12)$, because this point lies at distance $\sqrt{5/4}>1$ from any lattice point. So, you should take a bigger radius, like $\epsilon\sqrt{n}$.

> Then it is enough to show that $x_i\in [−b,b]$ belongs to one of the open intervals belonging to the balls.

I don't know what "intervals belonging to the balls" means, or why showing this is enough. Perhaps you are thinking of rectangular boxes?

Anyway, here's how you could proceed.

1. The open balls of radius $\sqrt{n}$ centered at $\mathbb Z^n$ cover $\mathbb R^n$. Indeed, for any $x$ the distance to the nearest integer lattice point is at most $\sqrt{n\cdot (1/2)^2} = \sqrt{n}/2$.
2. Therefore, the open balls of radius $\epsilon\sqrt{n}$ centered at $\epsilon\,\mathbb Z^n$ cover $\mathbb R^n$.
3. To cover $[-b,b]^n$, we don't  need all of the lattice. When $x\in [-b,b]^n$, a nearest point  of $\epsilon\,\mathbb Z^n$  belongs to $[-b-\epsilon/2,b+\epsilon/2]^n$, because we don't have to go for more than $\epsilon/2$ along any coordinate to find an integer multiple of $\epsilon$.